# Probability that the absolute value of a normal distribution is greater than another

Tags: normal-distribution

Greatly appreciate anyone that is willing to Help. I am thinking about the question of comparing the absolute value of normal distributions. Given $a > b$, $X$ ~ $N(0,a)$ and $Y$ ~ $N(0,b)$, what is the distribution of $|X| - |Y|$?

Comment: At first glance, I would think that it follows a skew normal distribution

Comment: The only difficulty is considering the bounds of integration.  We know that $|X|$ and $|Y|$ are in the first quadrant of the $|X|,|Y|$ plot.  Drawing the line $|Y|=|X|-z$ when $z \ge 0$, we should integrate first with respect to $|X|$ from $0$ to $|Y|+z$ and then with respect to $|Y|$ from $0$ to $\infty$.  Drawing the line $|Y|=|X|-z$ when $z \lt 0$, we should integrate first with respect to $|Y|$ from $|X|-z$ to $\infty$ and then with respect to $|X|$ from $0$ to $\infty$.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: This is not a homework problem. Simply a problem that came up in work that I have been thinking about.

Answer (score 6):

It may be shown that $|X| \sim HN(a)$ and $|Y| \sim HN(b)$, where $HN(\cdot)$ represents a half-normal distribution.  For completeness, the probability density functions of $|X|$ and $|Y|$ are
\begin{eqnarray*}
f_{|X|} (x) &=& \frac{\sqrt{2}}{a\sqrt{\pi}} \exp \left(-\frac{x^2}{2a^2}\right), \quad x>0 \\
f_{|Y|} (y) &=& \frac{\sqrt{2}}{b\sqrt{\pi}} \exp \left(-\frac{y^2}{2b^2}\right), \quad y>0.
\end{eqnarray*}
It is also useful to note that if $W \sim HN(\sigma)$, then the moment generating function of $W$ is
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mbox{E} \left[\exp \left(tW\right) \right] = 2 \exp \left(\frac{\sigma^2 t^2}{2}\right) \Phi \left(\sigma t\right),
\end{eqnarray*}
where $\Phi (\cdot)$ denotes the CDF of the standard normal distribution.

We wish to find the distribution of $Z = |X| - |Y|$.  By definition, the CDF of $Z$ of is defined as
\begin{eqnarray*}
F_{Z} (z) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} f_{|X|} (x) f_{|Y|} (y) \mbox{I} \left[x-y \le z\right] \mbox{d}x \mbox{d}y,
\end{eqnarray*}
where $\mbox{I} \left[\cdot\right]$ denotes the indicator function.  Note that the double integral takes place in the first quadrant and the indicator function specifies all points above the line $y = x-z$. Now if $z \ge 0$, this line will intersect the $x$-axis, otherwise it will intersect the $y$-axis.  Now ordering the integration appropriately will greatly simplify the double integral.  See the following plots where the dark black line denotes $y=x-z$ and the red lines denote the direction and bounds of integration (albeit not extended indefinitely).
[image]

Therefore, we can write the CDF of $Z$ as
\begin{eqnarray*}
F_{Z} (z) = \mbox{I} \left[z \ge 0 \right]\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{y+z} f_{|X|} (x) f_{|Y|} (y) \mbox{d}x \mbox{d}y + \mbox{I} \left[z \lt 0 \right]\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{x-z}^{\infty} f_{|X|} (x) f_{|Y|} (y) \mbox{d}y \mbox{d}x.
\end{eqnarray*}

In the first double integral, consider the change of variables from $(x,y)$ to $(v,y)$, where $v=x-y$.  The Jacobian of this transformation is $1$.  The transformation is useful since it removes the occurrence of $y$ in the bound of integration when differentiating with respect to $v$.  A similar transformation was defined for the second double integral.  Plugging these values in, we obtain
\begin{eqnarray*}
F_{Z} (z) = \mbox{I} \left[z \ge 0 \right]\int_{0}^{\infty} f_{|Y|} (y)  \int_{-\infty}^{z} f_{|X|} (v+y) \mbox{d}v \mbox{d}y + \mbox{I} \left[z \lt 0 \right]\int_{0}^{\infty} f_{|X|} (x) \int_{-\infty}^{z}  f_{|Y|} (x-v) \mbox{d}v \mbox{d}x.
\end{eqnarray*}

By Leibniz's integral rule (or the fundamental theorem of calculus), the PDF of $Z$ is
\begin{eqnarray*}
f_{Z} (z) &=& \mbox{I} \left[z \ge 0 \right]\int_{0}^{\infty} f_{|Y|} (y)  f_{|X|} (z+y) \mbox{d}y + \mbox{I} \left[z \lt 0 \right]\int_{0}^{\infty} f_{|X|} (x)   f_{|Y|} (x-z)  \mbox{d}x \\ 
&=& \mbox{I} \left[z \ge 0 \right]\int_{0}^{\infty} f_{|Y|} (y)  f_{|X|} (y+|z|) \mbox{d}y + \mbox{I} \left[z \lt 0 \right]\int_{0}^{\infty} f_{|X|} (x)   f_{|Y|} (x+|z|)  \mbox{d}x.
\end{eqnarray*}

These integrals may be solved quite simply by making use of the moment generating function result.  I shall only solve the first one.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} f_{|Y|} (y)  f_{|X|} (y+|z|) \mbox{d}y &=& \frac{2}{ab \pi}\exp \left(-\frac{z^2}{2a^2} \right) \int_{0}^{\infty} \exp \left(-\frac{|z|}{a^2} y \right) \exp \left(-\frac{y^2}{2} \left[\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}\right] \right) \mbox{d}y.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now the second term within the integral is proportional to a $HN(\sigma)$ PDF with $\sigma^2 = \frac{a^2b^2}{a^2+b^2}$ and the first term is of the form of the MGF with $t = - \frac{|z|}{a^2}$.  Hence, multiplying and dividing by the proportionality constant, $\frac{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{ab\sqrt{\pi}}$, it may be shown that the above reduces to
\begin{eqnarray*}
2 \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} (a^2+b^2)^{(-.5)} \exp \left(-\frac{z^2}{2(a^2+b^2)} \right) \Phi \left(-\frac{b}{a} \frac{|z|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right).
\end{eqnarray*}
Making use of the standard normal PDF $ \phi(\cdot)$, the above can be written as
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{4}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \phi\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)\Phi \left(-\frac{b}{a} \frac{|z|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right).
\end{eqnarray*}
Solving for the other portion of the PDF of $Z$, one will result in the equation
\begin{eqnarray*}
f_Z (z) = \begin{cases}
\frac{4}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \phi\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)\Phi \left(-\frac{b}{a} \frac{|z|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right), & \mbox{for } z \ge 0 \\
\frac{4}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \phi\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)\Phi \left(-\frac{a}{b} \frac{|z|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right), & \mbox{for } z \lt 0
\end{cases}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: After the 2nd display, did you mean to say $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the CDF of a standard **normal** distribution? (This, from possibly the site's most prolific maker of typos.)

Comment: @BruceET Yes, thank you!  Where was my brain?